# Error on Button keyword in Android

Tags: java, android, adt

Maybe it sounds silly, but I am getting an error on Button keyword (where it should not be).
I am a newbie, and looked almost everywhere. And everyone says that

```
Button b = findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

is correct.

My code:

```
package com.example.myfirstappnew;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button b = findViewById(R.id.button1);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

Here is the screenshot: 
http://pbrd.co/ZEsSw7

Comment: I see XML at the links, not images.

Comment: For your reference, Button is not a keyword; it is a class name.

Comment: Also, what error do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to change

```
Button b = findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

to

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

You also need to add

```
import java.widget.Button;
```

to your import statements at the top of your file. If you are using Eclipse, you should use it's "organize imports" feature (or whatever Eclipse calls it) to do this automagically for you.

Answer (score 3):

From what I see, you have an error because findViewById returns `View` and not `Button`, and you need to cast it to `Button`.

You need to cast the `Button` to a `Button`:

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

And add this import:

```
import android.widget.Button;
```

Next time, when you say you have an error please include it :)

Comment: This is also showing error on both words **Button** Screenshot: http://pbrd.co/ZEt8Lq

Answer (score 3):

findViewById returns View, you need to cast it into Button.

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

Edit:

Click on the first link that show i`mport import Button(android.widget.)`

or simply press `ctrl+shift+o`

Answer (score 3):

The code needs to import `Button` (as suggested in the top hint in the screenshot).